# How To Create Combined Search Filters In Views?

Tags: views

I am currently working on a view that allows me to search "title" of a content type along with 3 other exposed filters. But now I want users to not only be able to search "title" but also "category" field of the same content type, except "title" and "Category" fields need to be one filter.

I tried using contextual filters but I'm afraid I don't quite understand the best method. I'm currently using global:combine fields filter but instead my views results (which worked fine previously) no longer works. I'm trying to avoid complicated coding. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 15):

The newest version of Views integrates this feature without the need for Views filter populate.  It's a filter called ***Combine fields filter***.

To make use of it you first need to add all of the fields you want to filter on.  You may check *Exclude from display* if you want to search for it, but don't want to display it.

Once all of the fields are there, add a *Combine fields filter*, and choose to Expose it.  Choose **Single field** for the *Filter type to Expose*

This is a different approach than Views populate filter, but as this is integrated into Views I find it much more intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

We use this module all over the place, it works just like it says.  Only limitation is that it only works on String fields (Node Reference, Taxonomy ID, etc. won't work).

[Views filters populate](http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate)

> This is an utility module. Its sole purpose is to fill in one blank that seems not easy to be done using normal views, which is to use one exposed string filter to search on multiple fields.

Comment: hey thanks..hmm it might work but my categories field are also taxonomy terms linked from my content to taxonomy by node reference. :( Is there any way i can search both taxonomy and node IDs with just one input?