# Having Views searchable by users

Tags: 7, views, users, entities

I would like to be able to search my views by a field that is generated by an Entity Reference of users of the site.

**Attempt #1 - Combine Fields Filter**
I added this filter as exposed with the setting of "Contains" either from the "Title" field or the "Responsible Party" field (which is the Entity Reference field that is a list of users.  Here is a picture of the settings[image]
The results of this were that the title field is filterable as pictured here[image]
Yet the user generated field did not properly filter as shown here[image]

**Attempt #2 - Search: Search Terms filter**
Same process and same issues using this filter.  Here is a picture of the settings[image]

Then the same results as shown here.
Searching Title [image]
Searching Users  [image]

Comment: cool, I didn't know that you could combine fields filters. Just wondering, if you add an exposed filter of responsibly party (as a stand alone, not combined) does the filter work as expected? or do you still get blanks?

Comment: Ya the filter for responsible party works great alone.

Comment: You could try to add a relation of the entity reference field in the advanced section. It might expose the title as a field with its base on the referenced node, which might filter better. But it might also not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you did all the steps correctly, [How To Create Combined Search Filters In Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45000/how-to-create-combined-search-filters-in-views#57176), which leads me to believe that this is a bug.

Upon looking at the View's issues, I found **[Combined fields filter not working with entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/2450193).**

Therefore, you will have to use it as a standalone, not combined, filter until this bug is fixed, which does not look like it will be any time soon.

Comment: Alright.  Sad times as it seems that Views has over 1600 bugs so this is probably not getting fixed.   Thanks for the help though.